# Combinatorics Card problem

Tags: combinatorics

Consider this question, in how many ways can a gambler draw five cards from a standard deck of 52 and get a hand with a) full house and b) straight? I'm not sure if this is a doable question, but it was something that popped up in my hand when I was doing this other combinatorial question that had cards in it. Thanks to anyone who can show me how to solve this.

Comment: Take probability as successful outcomes over total outcomes. It should be straightforward from there.

Comment: You could take a glance at [Wikipedia's list of poker hands and probabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability#Frequency_of_5-card_poker_hands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring suit, there are $13 * 12$ different full houses ($13$ ways to pick the card that is in threes, $12$ ways to pick the card that is in twos). To account for suit, multiply by $4 * {4 \choose 2}$.

Again ignoring suit, there are $10$ ways to compose a straight. (Ace to five, deuce to six, three to seven, ..., ten to Ace). Each card can be one of four suits, so we multiply by $4^5$.

The total number of possible hands you could get is ${52 \choose 5}$

To find the probability, divide successful outcomes by total outcomes.